# How does one use selenium and python to interact with a rateit widget?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

This question might actually have been asked before, but I have scoured the net looking for the answer, but to no avail.

So my team has an automation project using selenium in python. The issue now is that on the website there is a "rateit" widget implemented, where one has to highlight a set out of five stars to give a rating.

This is the rateit widget: https://github.com/gjunge/rateit.js/wiki

I have tried everything from using the ActionChain.move_to_element to click element by off set.

Comment: The easiest for us has been to use a JS script with `driver.execute_script`, and calling the `.rateit` function

Comment: Code trials, relevant _HTML_ and error stack (if any) please.

Comment: @PrianshShah Thank you, this worked.